# Angular4 template bindings not working without functions in the component, after npm update

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I recently updated my NPM modules. I didnt really pay attention to what was updated unfortunately, but interestingly all my "in-template" angular binding stopped functioning.

IE.

```
<button type="submit"
        class="button button--full-width"
        [ngClass]='{"button--ajax-loading": showBtnAjaxLoader}'>
```

[image]

Aka. when the condition for and ngClass is true, it outputs undefined. I can try replaceing single quotes (') with ("), but this changes nothing.

Another example

before

```
<dropdown [ngClass]="{'dropdown__open': isDropDownOpen}">
```

the ngClass was working, now I have to put the function into the dropdown.ts as so

```
//TEMPLATE
<dropdown [ngClass]="getDropdownClasses()">

//COMPONENT
getDropdownClasses() {
    return {'dropdown__open': isDropDownOpen};
}
```

If the isDropDownOpen variable is true, the class added to the element is "undefined". Image as follows.

Any clues how I can fix this without manually going over all the code in this fairly large project?

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "brainbase-angular-cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@types/immutable": "^3.8.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.66",
    "angular-linkedin-sdk": "^0.1.7",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-tooltip": "^2.3.1",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.21",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-intercom": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.5.2",
    "ng2-sharebuttons": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "tinymce": "^4.5.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.0-beta.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: *Not working* is too broad

Comment: I'm sorry. I added an image to clarify what I mean.

Comment: I am not seeing you are binding to `ngClass` on `on-off-switch` component, you are doing it for `dropdown` component

Comment: Wrong picture. Sorry its late at night. I replaced my first example with a better one and an appropriate image.

Comment: Try using class binding and see if it works again, on the button, remove `ngClass` binding, and do this `[class.button--ajax-loading]="showBtnAjaxLoader"`, same goes for `dropdown`.

Comment: That works, but doesnt help, since I have inline many smaller equations throughout the project as not to make them functions in the component.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, something was wrong with my package.json and after updating the @angular dependancies, everything resolved itself.

This is my new package.json, if anyone cares.

```
{
  "name": "brainbase-angular-cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.2",
    "@types/immutable": "^3.8.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.66",
    "angular-linkedin-sdk": "^0.1.7",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-tooltip": "^2.3.1",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.21",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-intercom": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.5.2",
    "ng2-sharebuttons": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "tinymce": "^4.5.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  }
}
```